# Using custom operators with completion block

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, swift2

To cut story short let' say I have a operator defined:

```
infix operator <~ {
    associativity left
    precedence 160
}
```

Let's say i'm using this operator do to some work between two objects, so I've defined function like this:

```
func <~ <T: FirstProtocol, U:SecondProtocol>(lhs: T, rhs: U) {
    //async request
}
```

Now we can't return anything because operator function is doing async work, nor we can use more paramters for the closure. Because the async function might run for several second I need a callback that will run when the async task is finished. The question is if you can use operators with async functions? I've tried various solutions and none of them seems to work.

Perfect solution would look like this:

```
something <~ somethingElse {
    error in
    //async call finished
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this provided you're willing to setup up some scaffolding. There's no way this can work out of the box.

Lets think about how we might go about doing this without operators. We would have a queue of operations and as each one completed we'd add the next. And each operation should notify the queue once it is completed.

So the operators are just responsible for adding the operations to the queue. If you want a more sophisticated implementation look into any Promises library for Swift. I have attempted to put together a rudimentary working implementation of the concept :

```
var queue = NSOperationQueue()

infix operator <~ {
    associativity left
    precedence 160
}

struct QueuedOperation
{
    var operation : NSBlockOperation
}


func <~ (first: ()->(), second:()->())->QueuedOperation {

    let operationOne = NSBlockOperation(block: first)
    let operationTwo = NSBlockOperation(block: second)

    operationTwo.addDependency(operationOne)
    queue.addOperation(operationOne)
    queue.addOperation(operationTwo)

    return QueuedOperation(operation: operationTwo)
}

func <~ (first : QueuedOperation, second:()->())->QueuedOperation {

    let operationTwo = NSBlockOperation(block: second)

    operationTwo.addDependency(first.operation)
    queue.addOperation(operationTwo)

    return QueuedOperation(operation: operationTwo)
}



_ = {

    sleep(2)

    print("First")

    } <~ {

        sleep(4)

        print("Second")

    } <~ {

        sleep(8)
        print("Third")
}
```

So it works like this :

Operation1 <~ Operation2 <~ Operation3

Operation1 <~ Operation2

Calls the first implementation which puts both Operation1 & Operation2 on the queue and adds Operation1 as a dependency for Operation2. We return a QueuedOperation wrapping Operation2 from this because when we chain onwards the subsequent one has a dependency on Operation2 BUT Operation2 musn't be queued again.

Returning a different type and dispatching to a function with a different type signature allows us to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `something <~ somethingElse { err in ... }` is impossible because the compiler interpret it as `something <~ (somethingElse({ err in ... }))`.

At least, you have to `(something <~ somethingElse) { err in ... }`. Try this in the Playground:

```
import Foundation

infix operator <~ {
associativity left
precedence 160
}

func <~(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> ((Int) -> Void) -> Void {
    return { callback in
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            callback(lhs + rhs)
        }
    }
}

let a = 1
let b = 2

(a <~ b) { result in
    println("OK: \(result)")
}

dispatch_main()
```